# Is there anyway to bool 2dimensional array to integer in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean, typecast-operator

Guess there Is 2-dimensional bool array like this,

```
bool table[16][16] 

    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1  ...16[0][] ->1
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0  ...16[1][] ->2 
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1  ...16[2][] ->3
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1  ...16[3][] ->5
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1  ...16[4][] ->9
    ...
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1  ...16[15][] ->41
```

And I know all of the bool value are aligned in a sequential address.
Can I transform these array to int value using some type-cast function without using any arithmetic function? It seems like it is more natural way than calculating using pow function.

I used reinterpret_cast to solve it, But It doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds rather like a job to do with [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert bool array to int32 ,unsigned int and double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410186/convert-bool-array-to-int32-unsigned-int-and-double)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does not specify the way to store `bool`. Compilers may choose to store individual values as bytes or as any other type they like, so there is no no-op way of converting `bool` arrays to integers.

An array of [`std::bitset<16>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) could be used instead for a more compact representation. It also lets you get integral representation of the bits using `to_ulong` member function.

> It seems like it is more natural way than calculating using pow function.

If this approach does not work for you, you can still do it with bit operations, not with `power` function:

```
int res = 0;
for (int b = 0 ; b != 16 ; b++) {
    if (table[row][b]) {
        res |= (1 << b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your kindness. I had been just looking around to find direct way, but It doesn't fit for C++.